# How to replace region with own enum in AmazonEC2Client in c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

In my aspnet core 3.1 project I am using client for aws for getting all instance list for me.
In constructor AmazonEC2Client third parameter is class which is accepting RegionEndPoint, and I would like to put enum instead of RegionEndPoint.

My method looks like:

```
      public static async Task<List<string>> AwsList(string awsAccessKeyId, string 
     awsSecretAccessKey) // should AwsRegion region as 3rd paramater
    {
        AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsAccessKeyId,awsSecretAccessKey, 
        RegionEndpoint.EUWest1); // replace RegionEndpoint.EUWest1 with enum paramater

        bool done = false;
        var instanceIds = new List<string>();
        DescribeInstanceTypesRequest request = new DescribeInstanceTypesRequest();

        while (!done)
        {
            DescribeInstanceTypesResponse response = await 
           client.DescribeInstanceTypesAsync(request);
            foreach ( var instanceType in response.InstanceTypes.Where(x => 
            x.MemoryInfo.SizeInMiB >= 2048 && x.VCpuInfo.DefaultVCpus >= 2))
            {
                 instanceIds.Add(instanceType.InstanceType);
            }

            request.NextToken= response.NextToken;

            if (response.NextToken == null)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return instanceIds;
    }
```

I would like to 3rd parameter which is enum to my method and replace Region with enum. As there is no constructor which accepting enum, how I can specify AmazonECwClient constructor and specify enum using extension methods (if possible)

My enum which I want implement and replace.

```
    public enum AwsRegion
    {
        /// <summary>The US East (Virginia) endpoint.</summary>
        USEast1 = 1,
        /// <summary>The US East (Ohio) endpoint.</summary>
        USEast2 = 2,
        /// <summary>The US West (N. California) endpoint.</summary>
        USWest1 = 3,
        /// <summary>The US West (Oregon) endpoint.</summary>
        USWest2 = 4,
        /// <summary>The EU West (Ireland) endpoint.</summary>
        EUWest1 = 5,
        /// <summary>The EU Central (Frankfurt) endpoint.</summary>
        EUCentral1 = 6,
        /// <summary>The Asia Pacific (Tokyo) endpoint.</summary>
        APNortheast1 = 7,
        /// <summary>The Asia Pacific (Seoul) endpoint.</summary>
        APNortheast2 = 8,
        /// <summary>The Asia Pacific (Mumbai) endpoint.</summary>
        APSouth1 = 9,
        /// <summary>The Asia Pacific (Singapore) endpoint.</summary>
        APSoutheast1 = 10,
        /// <summary>The Asia Pacific (Sydney) endpoint.</summary>
        APSoutheast2 = 11,
        /// <summary>The South America (Sao Paulo) endpoint.</summary>
        SAEast1 = 12,
        /// <summary>The US GovCloud West (Oregon) endpoint.</summary>
        USGovCloudWest1 = 13,
        /// <summary>The China (Beijing) endpoint.</summary>
        CNNorth1 = 14
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this source code of `aws-sdk-net` [RegionEndpoint.cs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/cf58111923e9dda385a2ac34d6a5dee5f32b1c24/sdk/src/Core/RegionEndpoint/RegionEndpoint.cs) will help you deal with region mapping.

Even `AWSSDK` has a dictionary in order to quickly convert a region string to its static **RegionEndpoint** object.

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, RegionEndpoint> _hashBySystemName = new Dictionary<string, RegionEndpoint>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

 /// <summary>
/// Gets the region based on its system name like "us-west-1"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="systemName">The system name of the service like "us-west-1"</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static RegionEndpoint GetBySystemName(string systemName)
{
// ...skip
    if (_hashBySystemName.TryGetValue(systemName, out regionEndpoint))
        return regionEndpoint;
// ...skip    
}
```

Which means you can have your own dictionary and a converting method.

```cs
private static Dictionary<AwsRegion, RegionEndpoint> _awsRegionDict = new Dictionary<AwsRegion, RegionEndpoint>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

public static RegionEndpoint ConvertByAwsRegion(AwsRegion emAwsRegion)
{
    if (_awsRegionDict.TryGetValue(emAwsRegion, out regionEndpoint))
        return regionEndpoint;

    return RegionEndpoint.EUWest1; // your default region
}
```

Offering another extension method would make it easiler to use.

```cs
public static class RegionEndpointExtension
{
    public RegionEndpoint ToRegionEndpoint(this AwsRegion region)
    {
        return AwsRegionProvider.ConvertByAwsRegion(region)
    }
}
```

Thus, use your `AwsRegion` enum as 3rd argument, then calling `ConvertByAwsRegion` or `ToRegionEndpoint` converting method on demand.